# jQuery Uploadify Plugin: Safari: Nothing happens when clicking Upload button

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, uploadify

I am using the Uploadify jQuery plugin. It works fine in Firefox, etc. but in Safari nothing happens when I click the Upload button.

Has anyone else had this problem before? I have no idea what's causing it.

Comment: is this the basic version or html5 version? , cuz according to theofficial website html5 has problems. UploadiFive currently works in the latest versions of FireFox and Chrome and should be supported in future versions of IE and Safari. A fallback can be set for browsers that do not support the HTML5 File API.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it's related, but in Mavericks, I've been running into an issue if the preference "Stop plug-ins to save power" is set. Uploadify will work as expected if that isn't set. Hope that helps!

[image: Safari Preferences]